# Obrigatoriedade de campos

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Tenho dois campos do tipo texto, onde um é CEP e o outro é Endereço.

/no campo CEP eu uso a API de CEP, quando digito um CEP ele completa os outros campos com os resultados. Preciso de uma seguinte validação:

- Fazer uma validação em 2 campos
- SE O CAMPO CEP for VAZIO,
- ENDEREÇO deve ser obrigátorio, SE NÃO,
- CEP é OBRIGATÓRIO

Segue uma pequena imagem do meu formulário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Conforme vai preenchendo as informações, ou no final através de um botão? Ou em ambas?

Comment: @Everson tem um botão que fazer a validação no final do formulario

Comment: @Renan ja tentei e não consegui fazer a validação

Comment: Required obriga sempre a estar preenchido, por isso não pode ser utilizado para a mesma validação.

Comment: @Everson sim, só que se um estiver branco o outro vai ser obrigatorio vice-versa

Comment: Para ajudar na lógica: https://jsfiddle.net/pf1b7moa/

Comment: @Everson isso mesmo, funcionou!

Comment: @LeonardoMacedo minha resposta serviu ? porque você a modificou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplo funcional, qualquer coisa poste nos comentários.

```js
$(function(){
  $('input').on('focusout',function(){
    if(this.value === ''){
      $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
    }else{
      $(this).css('border','');
    }
  });
  
  $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
      if(this.value === ''){
        alert('Campo vazio.');
        $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="CEP" name="cep" id="cep">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Endereço" name="endereco" id="endereco">
<input type="button" value="Salvar">
```